# Firebug binary variable

Tags: javascript, firebug

Hy,

I have a binary array that comes from deflating a string using [this library](https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate).
I want to see the contents of the array in hex in firebug's console.

It's possible to do this? If it's possible, how can I do?

Of course, I tried `console.log(array)` in `raw_deflating.js` but it shows some garbage(of course, because it's binary)

I searched a lot on net, and surprisingly no one has asked this before.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer to my own question, if someone will have the same question:

Unfortunately, Firebug hasn't this feature. You can't see in debugger the hex value of a variable.

But, in my particular case, I was able to see the dec value of the variables directly from JavaScript, because the char array comes from `String.fromCharCode(buff[j]);`.

So, if you have a byte array, you can inspect the content using JS function `String.charCodeAt()`